# Clarification regarding integral of $\arcsin (\sqrt x)$

Tags: integration

I need to integrate $\arcsin (\sqrt x)$. I tried using integration by parts but going wrong somewhere. Please help.

\begin{align}
&x\arcsin (\sqrt x)-\frac {1}{2}\int \frac{x}{\sqrt{x-x^2}}\,dx \\
&=x\arcsin (\sqrt x)-\frac {1}{2}\int \frac{x-1/2}{\sqrt{1/4-(x-1/2)^2}}dx+\frac {1}{2}\int \frac{1/2}{\sqrt{1/4-(x-1/2)^2}}\,dx\\
&=x\arcsin (\sqrt x)+\frac {1}{2}\sqrt {x-x^2}+ \frac {1}{4}\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{1/4-(x-1/2)^2}}\,dx\\
&=x\arcsin (\sqrt x)+\frac {1}{2}\sqrt{(x-x^2)}+ (1/4)\arcsin ((x-1/2)/(1/2))
\end{align}

But the answer given in my book is $-1/2\arcsin (\sqrt x)(1-2x)+1/2\sqrt x\sqrt{1-x}$

Btw I took 1 as the first function while applying integration by parts.

Comment: An easier approach is $u = \sqrt x$, so that $dx = 2u$. Then parts.

Comment: I don't want to know the easier approach.I'm asking what is wrong in my approach.

Comment: last term should be $(1/4) \arcsin (2x-1)$ which equals   $-(1/2) \arcsin (\sqrt x) -\pi/8$

Comment: @DougM: The last term is actually already $(1/4) \arcsin (2x-1)$.

Comment: @joriki  You are correct, I am going a little cross-eyed.

Answer (score 1):

You've made a mistake with the signs.

$$-\frac {1}{2}\int \frac{x}{\sqrt{x-x^2}}\,dx = -\frac 12 \left(\int \frac{x-\frac12}{\sqrt{\frac 14-(x-\frac 12)^2}}dx+\int \frac{\frac 12}{\sqrt{\frac 14-(x-\frac 12)^2}}\,dx\right)$$

Notice the negative factors into the 2nd integral as well, which you overlooked.

[Differentiating the result](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=d%2Fdx(x+sin%5E(-1)(sqrt(x))%2Bsqrt(x-x%5E2)%2F2-1%2F4+sin%5E(-1)(2+x-1))) with this issue resolved yields the correct answer.